# Hello, I am facing problems with my code, I am attaching the code as well as the error output I am receiving

Tags: python

the code-

```
def minimum(n):
    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = eval(input("enter number 1:"))
        y = eval(input("enter number 2:"))
        if x or y== "\n":
            print("please enter valid value")
        l = [x,y]
        L.append(l)
    print("input keyset-",L)
    for i in range(n):
        if L[i][0] < L[i][1]:
            r = L[i]
            print("FIRST","\t",r)
        elif L[i][0] == L[i][1]:
            r = L[i]
            print("ANY","\t",r)
        else:
            r = L[i]
            print("SECOND","\t",r)

print(minimum(4))
```

I was getting this error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ban\Documents\BAANI\code s 1.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(minimum(4))
  File "c:\Users\Ban\Documents\BAANI\code s 1.py", line 5, in minimum
    y = eval(input("enter number 2:"))
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: try rerunning it it works for me, EOF while parsing mainly mean that you're missing a parenthesis r : .. something in the syntax

Comment: Don't use eval for this. Also, *if x or y== "\n":* will not do what you expect. Maybe you should explain exactly what you're trying to achieve by showing sample input and the output you need

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Restart your python kernel, clean your python cache files, and re-run.

Comment: Please share what you are trying to input. Obviously it has something to do with the data you enter in  the input.

Comment: When using eval in this way you will get a syntax error if the input is empty because it's effectively *eval('')*

Comment: @Vlad True, `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` is an error generated by eval()

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and inputting 1, 2, etc... and it worked fine, so the issue is likely caused by your input. However, your code has some issues :

- In order to convert the string returned by `input`, you use `eval`. This is a really bad idea, as what `eval` does is interpret its argument as Python source code, and return the result. What you want to do is way simpler than that, you just want to convert a string to a number. Instead of `eval(input("enter number 1:"))`, you should use `float(input("enter number 1:"))`. I can't be 100% sure, but I guess that your use of `eval` is what causes your issue
- For (I guess) checking that the inputted values are non-empty, you use :
  `if x or y== "\n":`
  This is interpreted as "if x is true or y is a newline character". This is not at all what you want! Since x and y are outputs of `eval`, you don't know what their type will be, and if using the program correctly, they likely won't be strings, so the comparison to a given string is going to be False (side note: `input` trims the trailing `\n`, so when checking for emptiness of an input string, you should use `if x == "":` or just `if not x:`)
- After checking if the input is correct, even if the input is invalid, you go along and use it. You should instead use a `while` loop
- Finally, when iterating over `L`, since you only care about `L[i]` (and not `i` per se), you should use `for elt in L` (`elt` being the `L[i]` you used)

With all this, I would rewrite your code to this:

```
def minimum(n):
    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        while True:
            try:
                x = float(input("Enter number 1:"))
                y = float(input("Enter number 2:"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter valid value")
            else: break
        
        L.append([x, y])
    
    print(f"Input keyset: {L}")
    for elt in L:
        if elt[0] < elt[1]: print("FIRST","\t", elt)
        elif elt[0] == elt[1]: print("ANY","\t", elt)
        else: print("SECOND","\t", elt)

minimum(4)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer, when I had not even properly framed my question! my doubt was actually that, in the event of no input to the "enter number 1 or 2" why was an error coming, and if there was a way of removing that. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
 if x or y== "\n":
       print("please enter valid value")
```

which always evaluates to True

`if x` or `if y == '\n'`

True or False = True --> print (enter valid value)

it'll only evaluate to False if both entries are empty, which is not what you want.

what you want to do is:

```
 if x =='\n' or y== "\n":
        print("please enter valid value")
```

**also** `eval(input("enter number 1:"))` will throw an **exception** when sent an empty string `''`, `'\n'` or `' '`, whech might be causing the **EOF** error, if after removing it, you are still getting **EOF**, you want to consider resetting the project or the python file

I've tested the code after the fix it works fine, **there's no issue with the logic**.

Comment: While true it's unrelated to the problem that the OP is asking about, which is related to the input and the `eval` calls.

Comment: Actually that won't **always** evaluate to True. If the input is an empty string then *x* is falsy

Comment: @Vlad you are right

Answer (score 0):

```
def minimum(n):
    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = eval(input("enter number 1:"))
        y = eval(input("enter number 2:"))
        if "\n" in (x, y):
            print("please enter valid value")
        l = [x,y]
        L.append(l)
    print("input keyset-", L)
    for i in range(n):
        if L[i][0] < L[i][1]:
            r = L[i]
            print("FIRST","\t",r)
        elif L[i][0] == L[i][1]:
            r = L[i]
            print("ANY","\t",r)
        else:
            r = L[i]
            print("SECOND","\t",r)

minimum(4)
```

but there have more efficient way use min lib:

```
def minimum(n):
    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        x = eval(input("enter number 1:"))
        y = eval(input("enter number 2:"))
        if "\n" in (x, y):
            print("please enter valid value")
        L.append((x, y))
    print("input keyset-", L)
    for pair in L:
        n = min(*pair)
        print(f"the min number: {n}")

minimum(4)
```

---

### UPDATE: what going on at EOL error

when you try to access user input, you wanna parsing it to int, but python cannot handle it when input is not valid.

```py
x = input("enter number") # x is string now
n = int(x) # n is int
```

and when you parsing empty string x into int, you will get parsing error, for that reason, you should add error handle

```py
x = input("enter number") # x is string now
try:
  n = int(x) # n is int
except Exception as e:
  # error
  print(str(e))
  continue
```

do not use eval at this case, no needed, if it is necessary, catch error is the only way to solve it.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the original problem being asked about. Which has to do with invalid input for `eval`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean how to solve EOL error?